# DotNet Core App 2.1 - Can't add DLL reference

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a DotNetCore 2.1 Web App (just created it today from the VS 2017 scaffold).  This solution also includes a DotNet Core 2.1 Library DLL project.  The solution builds ok.

I have another (brand new) DotNetCore 2.1 Web App that wants to use the Library DLL.  But when I try to add a new reference (on the Browse tab), it complains:

> One or more errors occurred.
>   The reference is invalid or unsupported.

Any suggestions?

(Curiously, the DLL doesn't show up directly under the Bin\Debug folder like it does in classic .Net;  It's under Bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1)

Comment: Is the dll marked as `None` or `Content` build action? is there an entry in the csproj file related to the dll?

Comment: No and no.  The DLL doesn't exist in the referencing project.  I'm trying to add an external DLL to my project references, and it just won't do it.  A little Googling showed that this flavor of problem seems to infect DotNet Core libraries...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a new project from the Visual Studio 2017 `Class Library (.NET Core)` template, the csproj file contains:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
```

Since this is a library, it (apparently) needs to target `netstandard2.0`.  (BTW, creating a library project from the `dotnet` command line command correctly targets `netstandard2.0`.  Go figure.)

So changing the line in the library's csproj file to

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

and rebuilding the library now allows me to reference the library from the DotNet Core 2.1 (`netcoreapp2.1`) application.

Comment: But overall it is unnecessary to add a reference like that. A .NET Core Class Library project can generate a NuGet package directly, and then you can add package reference (which resolves all the dependencies).

Comment: But what can you do if this is a third-party library and you have no control of how it compiles?

Comment: The whole point of the OP was that I have a solution containing (1) my application project, and (2) a general-purpose library project. In the context of this solution, both projects are what I'm working on. Note that the OP says I'm using a **project** reference, not a DLL reference. The whole point of this is to develop both the app and the library in one VS solution. The underlying problem was that the VS template code set up the csproj file for the library incorrectly.

Comment: @AnKing If you've been given a 3rd-party library, and it's not built correctly, my guess is that you are stuck unless you can get the library's author to fix it. I imagine there are ways to work around an incompatibility like that, but that would be a subject for a different SO question of its own. Good luck!

Comment: in my case it worked after changing the target framework from  `netcore6.0` to `net6.0` the name was wrong in the newer versions.

Answer (score 17):

I got this error after I moved some of my code repos around and suddenly my .NET Core 2.1 console app wouldn't recognize a .NET 4.5 DLL anymore when I added it.

Turned out that although the broken reference did not show in the solution explorer, the project file still contained it, along with the now broken HintPath to the DLL's old location. Manually removing this reference from the project file solved it.

Comment: This was the problem. I edited the project, removed the section and added the reference back in with no problems.

Answer (score 8):

Go into your .csproj and make sure the `<Reference Include=...` is pointing to the correct directory.

For example, my references were pointing to the `bin\Debug` path of another project when the only build that was actually there was the `bin\Release`

Answer (score 2):

I am converting lots of projects to .net6, and one of the projects suddenly refused to let me add .dll files. The solution was to remove the old references first, then add the new references. (The project had references to old .dll files with the same name as the new converted ones.)

Normally Visual Studio lets me add two dlls with the same name but different path, so I later can erase the old one, but in this particular case this did not work. A screenshot and Paint to the rescue for my memory!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a reference to duplicated .dll files. After removing duplication and changing references to different folders got the error above. Cleaning `obj`, `bin` and removing the `.vs` folder from the root directory helped

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to add a nuget package instead of manually adding a reference. I was using .net 6 and needed System.Drawing so I added the System.Drawing.Common package.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/